# How is Tahajjud prayed?

Tags: salat, tahajjud, witr

I never prayed Tahajjud before. Now I have found out about its importance and reward. But I am having some misunderstanding regarding how to pray it. Let me explain with real example.

I was praying like this (When I didn't pray Tahajjud):

**Isha** (for example at 18:30)

- 4 rakats Fard
- 2 rakats Sunnah
- 3 rakats Witr

**Fajr** (for example at 6:40)

- 2 rakats Sunnah
- 2 rakats Fard

---

And Yestersay I prayed like this:

**Isha** (18:30)

- 4 rakats Fard
- 2 rakats Sunnah
- 3 rakats Witr

**Tahajjud** (at 2:00)

- 20 rakats

**Fajr** (at 6:40)

- 2 rakats Sunnah
- 2 rakats Fard

---

**But**

Today I read that after Tahajjud I must pray **Witr**. Which Witr is referred here is confusing me. The one I was praying in Isha or **is it a separate Witr**?

**For Allah's sake, can anyone help me to understand how to pray Tahajjud and what kind of Witr I must pray in the end?**

**Additionally, the sources about Tahajjud are saying that Quran must be recited as well, as much as possible. Please, tell me where I must read Quran?**

Comment: As if searching by [tag:tahajjud] gives not the hint of an answer. Duplicate posts are not what we are looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> [Narrated Ibn Abbas](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/19/19): The prayer of the Prophet (ﷺ) used to be of
>   thirteen rak`at, i.e. of the night prayer.

It's all after Isha and before Fajr:

- 2 Rikat Isha Sunnah
- 8 Rikat Tahajjud (2 by 2)
- 3 Rikat Witr

> [Narrated `Abdullah bin`Umar](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/14/9): The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Make witr as
>   your last prayer at night."

Better to pray Witr after Isha if you are not regular and not sure to wake up for Tahajjud.

Comment: Your answer is much better. Thank you. Jazakkallahu khayran!

Answer (score -1):

It be the same witr that you pray after isha. Witr should be the last prayer after all nawafal so if you pray tahajjud then witr should be placed after it.

> Make witr as your last prayer at night.
>
> https://sunnah.com/bukhari/14/9

Comment: @Bahrom it means what you interpret of it. If you memorize qur'an than recit what ever you want and can at the situation of it else you might be allowed to recite from a Moshaf. If you mean how and when then it is easy tahajjud is a prayer so when are you supposed to recite qur'an?